# position image in lower right hand corner of div without absolute position

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to position an image in the lower right hand corner of a div without using absolute positioning. I don't want to use absolute positioning because the text wrap then fails (as I have float right applied to the image, and I want to have text wrap applied). If I place the image inside the div, I have to place it after a closing p tag to get it to somewhat work. I don't want to use this method as the bottom of the image and the end of the text does not line up at the bottom.
any ideas?

```
.bottom-right-img{position:relative;width:203px;height:277px;float:right;margin-left:15px;}
.right-col{position:relative;width:410px;margin-top:15px;text-indent:15px;margin-right:61px;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qoy8tz7x/1/

Answer (score 0):

Based on your jsfiddle, would the following work? I changed the position to bottom-right.

```
.bottom-right-img{position:bottom-right;width:203px;height:220px;float:right;margin-left:15px;}
.right-col{position:relative;width:410px;margin-top:15px;text-indent:15px;margin-right:61px;}
```

Comment: no, you also changed the height of the image to 220px. I need the image to stay at the same specified width in my original post.

Comment: *sorry, same specified height (not width)